# Outlook conversation view turned off but it still keeps showing up and attachments in string of replies hidden

Tags: microsoft-outlook, attachments

Attachment(the first one) in string of replies is hidden. The first email sent to me had an attachment that is not visible anymore(no way to see it). But the reply I sent with an attachment is visible.

I did my best to turn off conversation view but it is not going off. This error has been there for 10 years in outlook! Or perhaps it keeps coming back for 10 years!!

Answer (score 0):

As I know, in Outlook desktop client, it is by design that only the attachment in this current email message will be displayed. And if you want to check the first attachment in the first email, you need to find the first email within your mailbox.

To remove all customizations to the view, please try to reset your view settings via View > Current View > Reset View or you can run the /cleanviews command  (Press Win + R, type “Outlook.exe /cleanviews”, press Enter) and see if there is any difference. If necessary, remember to back up first.

If I have any misunderstanding, feel free to let me know.

Comment: I can find attachment from previous 2 emails but not the first one. So attachment only for current one is wrong. "you need to find the first email within your mailbox" It is always there as part of the chain as the last email(no other way to access it). Just the text and that does not fulfil the requirement at hand. will check the 'cleanviews' later

Comment: Would mind adding screenshots of your attachment issue in your OP so that I could have a better understand of your issue?